# Error: '\l' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'<path to>\l"

Tags: r

I install R-4.1.1arm64 on m1 Mac.
When I type `R` in the terminal, it creates an error

[image]

Besides, when I use the Rscript command it will also generate the error.
I am not familiar with programming. Could anyone tell me a clear way to fix it?
Thanks, guys.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your `>` after the `Error` says that you are in an R session. There is no further harm, foul, error, you can proceed. As to where the `\l` entered into your process, you don't provide enough info, though perhaps some remnant from a saved prior session. Try starting a completely new session in a new directory...HTH

Comment: You probably have a startup script (`.Rprofile`) which does something it shouldn't. I am assuming you didn't install it from the r-project website so you should send this as a bug report to whoever provided you the installer.

Comment: You are right. I found ".Rprofile" that "options(langserver_library = '<path to>\languageserver-library')". I do not know what it is. May I just delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no problem now. I just delete the file ".Rprofile" and install the package "languageserver".

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.